# Why Codeigniter is showing same data on every page using pagination?

Tags: codeigniter

Codeigniter is showing the same data on every page using pagination. I think there is a problem in the `URL` formed as its unable to get **3rd uri** segment from the **url**.

> http://127.0.0.1/hmvc/business_list/?p=2

and the code i used is...

```
public function index()
{



    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM categories');
    $pagination_limit = '10';

    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'business_list/';

    $config['display_pages'] = true;
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';

    $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = $pagination_limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination pagination-right margin-none'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tagl_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    $data['results'] = $this->Business_model->fetch_comments_data($config['per_page'], $page);

    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

     $data['title'] = "Business List";

    $this->load->view('categories',$data);

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this :

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
```

To

```
$page = ($this->input->get('p') ? $this->input->get('p') : 0);
```

I think **Codeigniter URI Segment** not work in your case because if you url is like that

```
http://127.0.0.1/hmvc/business_list/page/2
```

then the first segment is `business_list` and second is `page` but you use query string so need to change

Comment: Is it possible to change from http://127.0.0.1/hmvc/business_list/?p=2 to http://127.0.0.1/hmvc/business_list/2 i used $config['page_query_string'] = false; but geeting 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Well take a time to understand what are you doing there.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM categories');
```

Looks like you are not defining **LIMIT** and **OFFSET**.

i found a nice example about [pagination with codeigniter](https://www.formget.com/pagination-in-codeigniter/) to you.

Comment: Did that in 4th last line of the code

$data['results'] = $this->Business_model->fetch_comments_data($config['per_page'], $page);

Comment: I think the problem here is URL formed. take a look